# Get data from Retrofit call and send it to another activity

Tags: android, asynchronous, android-activity, retrofit, call

I need to send the detail when I click on an item in a RecyclerView to another Activity..

```
// Here I call my service
public void getContactoById(Integer id) 
{
    apiManager.getContactoById(id).
            enqueue(new Callback<Contacto>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<Contacto> call, Response<Contacto> response) {
                    if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                        // ???????? How send from here to 2nd Activity
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<Contacto> call, Throwable t) {
                    Throwable x = t;
                }
            });
}

// In second Activity, I need to fill these controls with the values obtained from the service call
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail_contact);
  Service.getInstance().getContactoById(Integer.valueOf(contacto.getUserId()));

    imgFoto = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgFoto);
    tvNombre = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvNombre);
    tvPhoneHome = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvPhoneHome);
    tvPhoneCellphone = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvPhoneCellphone);
    tvPhoneOffice = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvPhoneOffice);
    tvBirthDate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvBirthDate);
}
```

I have to do it calling with Retrofit but the values remain empty because the Response arrives seconds after the start of the second Activity. Can the controls be updated from the Call Response? Thank you.

Comment: hi Andrew, it's easy, just use pass data with interface ...

Comment: Do you have any links with examples? Thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: Absolutely yes, just wait a moment, I send to you example code, your welcome!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best method is to pass the data through an **interface**.
Since your response is in asynchronous task, we need to pass it through an **interface**.

This interface can be implemented in activity where data [ your api response ] is required.

### I will show you how how it can be done:

Step 1: you need create interface and define function

```
public interface onAddTextViewCustomListener {
    void onAddText(String text);
}
```

Step 2: use this interface in 'onResponse' of your retrofit call

```
//declare interface object
 onAddTextViewCustomListener onAddTextViewCustomListener; //listener custom

//add contructor
  this.onAddTextViewCustomListener = onAddTextViewCustomListener;

//call interface and pass data
 onAddTextViewCustomListener.onAddText("your api response");
```

Step 3:
 Implements the interface to activity like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements onAddTextViewCustomListener
```

You will get the method defined inside interface in that activity after implementing it.

```
  public void onAddText(String text) {
        Log.i("API RESPONSE", text);
```

// execute your logic here.
        }

Comment: Excellent answer! It worked for me, just what I needed. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

it's my last project and I wish to help you:

create an adapter for your recyclerview, like below:

```
 public class ListAddressAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ListAddressAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
Context context;
List<ShippingInfoResponse> list;
ApiInterface apiInterface;
SelectAddress addressClicked;
deleteAddress deleteClicked;
boolean cardViewClicked = false;

public ListAddressAdapter(Context context, List<ShippingInfoResponse> list) {
    this.context = context;
    this.list = list;
}

@Override
public ListAddressAdapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.adress_list_item, parent, false);
    return new ListAddressAdapter.MyViewHolder(itemView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ListAddressAdapter.MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    holder.cardView.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
    holder.txtShowName.setText(list.get(position).getName());
    holder.txtShowProvince.setText(list.get(position).getProvince());
    holder.txtShowCity.setText(list.get(position).getCity());
    holder.txtShowAddress.setText(list.get(position).getCity()+" "+list.get(position).getAddress());
    holder.txtShowNumber.setText(list.get(position).getMobile());
    holder.txtEdit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, AddAddressActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("id", list.get(position).getId());
            intent.putExtra("name", list.get(position).getName());
            intent.putExtra("province", list.get(position).getProvince());
            intent.putExtra("city", list.get(position).getCity());
            intent.putExtra("address", list.get(position).getAddress());
            intent.putExtra("postalCode", list.get(position).getPostalCode());
            intent.putExtra("mobile", list.get(position).getMobile());
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    holder.txtSelect.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            addressClicked.selectAddress(
                    list.get(position).getName(),
                    list.get(position).getAddress(),
                    list.get(position).getMobile(),
                    list.get(position).getId(),
                    list.get(position).toString()
            );
            Log.e("select", "clicked");

        }
    });
    holder.txtDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            deleteClicked.deleteAddress(list.get(position).getId());

        }
    });
}


@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return list.size();
}

public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView txtName, txtShowName;
    TextView txtProvince, txtShowProvince;
    TextView txtCity, txtShowCity;
    TextView txtAddress, txtShowAddress;
    TextView txtNumber, txtShowNumber;
    TextView txtDelete;
    TextView txtEdit;
    CardView cardView;
    LinearLayout linearTxtEdit;
    TextView txtSelect;

    public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        txtName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_name_in_list_address);
        txtShowName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_show_name);
        txtProvince = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_province_in_list_address);
        txtShowProvince = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_show_province);
        txtCity = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_city_in_list_address);
        txtShowCity = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_show_city);
        txtAddress = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_address_in_list_address);
        txtShowAddress = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_show_address);
        txtNumber = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_number_in_list_address);
        txtShowNumber = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_show_number);
        txtEdit = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_edit);
        cardView = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardItem_address);
        linearTxtEdit = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.linearTxtEdit);
        txtSelect = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_select_address);
        txtDelete = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_delete_Address);

        txtEdit.setTypeface(Application.vazirDigit);
        txtName.setTypeface(Application.vazirDigit);
        txtShowName.setTypeface(Application.vazirDigit);
        txtProvince.setTypeface(Application.vazirDigit);
        txtShowProvince.setTypeface(Application.vazirDigit);
        txtCity.setTypeface(Application.vazirDigit);
        txtShowCity.setTypeface(Application.vazirDigit);
        txtAddress.setTypeface(Application.vazirDigit);
        txtShowAddress.setTypeface(Application.vazirDigit);
        txtNumber.setTypeface(Application.vazirDigit);
        txtShowNumber.setTypeface(Application.vazirDigit);
        txtSelect.setTypeface(Application.vazirDigit);
        txtDelete.setTypeface(Application.vazirDigit);
    }
}

public interface SelectAddress {
    public void selectAddress(String name, String address, String number, int id, String position);
}

public void setOnSelectAddressClicked(SelectAddress selectAddressClicked) {
    this.addressClicked = selectAddressClicked;
}


public interface deleteAddress {
    public void deleteAddress(int id);
}


public void setOnDeleteClicked(deleteAddress deleteAddressClicked) {
    this.deleteClicked = deleteAddressClicked;
}
```

}

and in your Activity :

```
 private void fillRecyclerView() {
    adapter = new ListAddressAdapter(this, info);
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    avl.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    adapter.setOnSelectAddressClicked(new ListAddressAdapter.SelectAddress() {

        @Override
        public void selectAddress(String name, String address, String number, int id, String position) {
            Name = name;
            Address = address;
            Number = number;
            Id = id;
            deleteId=id;
            Log.e("Name", name);
            SelectAddressFromList();
        }

    });
    adapter.setOnDeleteClicked(new ListAddressAdapter.deleteAddress() {
        @Override
        public void deleteAddress(int id) {
            deleteId = id;
            Log.w("id", deleteId + "");
            deleteLastAddress();
            avl.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    });
}

private void deleteLastAddress() {
    apiInterface = ApiClient.getClient(this).create(ApiInterface.class);
    Call<Void> call = apiInterface.deleteAddress(deleteId);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Void> call, Response<Void> response) {
            Log.w("responceCodeDelete", response.code() + "");
            Log.w("responceMessage", response.message());
            info.clear();
            avl.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            getAllAddress();


        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Void> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });
}

private void SelectAddressFromList() {
    apiInterface = ApiClient.getClient(this).create(ApiInterface.class);
    Call<Void> call = apiInterface.sendShippingInfo(
            Name,

            "خوزستان"
            , "اهواز",
            Address,
            "4947118914",
            Number
    );
    call.enqueue(new Callback<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Void> call, Response<Void> response) {
            Log.w("RspncCodSendAddressFrmLst", response.code() + "");
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.putExtra("Name", Name);
                intent.putExtra("Address", Address);
                intent.putExtra("id", Id);
                Log.w("sendingId", Id + "");
                setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
                deleteLastAddress();
                finish();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Void> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: What is ApiInterface, its a custom class? What was your goal in this project? Send detail from address to another Activity? Thank you!

Comment: ApiInterface is class who I   define required methods for using retrofit, its food delivery app in work in Iran, yes it's, your welcome

Comment: if you want to learn retrofit i suggest to you visit this web site:https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-getting-started-and-android-client

Comment: Thank you for all, I will try this solution.

Answer (score 0):

other way you may use something like

```
Intent intX=new Intent(this, otherActivity.class);
intX.putExtra("stringextra1","value extra1");
intX.putExtra("stringextra2","value extra2"); 
intX.putExtra("stringextra_x","value extra_x");
startActivityForResult(intX, 0);
```

and on otherActivity class receive that extra string

Answer (score 0):

> Use Bundle

In Activity1, pass data:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Activity2.class);    
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("key1",value1);
bundle.putInt("key2",value2);
...
intent.putExtras(bundle)
startActivity(intent);
```

In Activity2, retrieve data:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if (extras != null) {
    String value1 = extras.getString("key1");
    int value2 = extras.getInt("key2");
    ...
}
```

Comment: The problem is that the values of the first Activity are obtained asynchronously by Retrofit call, several seconds after the second Activity started.

Comment: So must start Activity 2 in @Override public void onResponse

Answer (score 0):

Create an array list and by the time, you fetch data from api, add it to an Arraylist.
After that in your adapter, use data from that arraylist to send data from one activity to another activity.

```
tv_title.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(mContext,WebviewActivity.class);
                  i.putExtra(INTENT_CHANNELURL,al_details.get(getLayoutPosition()).get(URL_WEB).toString ());
            i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            mContext.startActivity(i);
        }
    });
```

In my case, i created an Arraylist named al_details.